# Type changes to nonetype upon entering loop

Tags: python, class, linked-list

I'm a little bit new to Python and am working with a linked list. final_curr seems to work fine prior to entering the while loop and there's no problem with printing its next before the loop, but the same exact line of code in the loop results in the error "'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'next'". Why is this behavior happening?

```
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        final_curr = ListNode(10)
        final_list = final_curr

        print(final_curr.next)
        while list1 and list2:
            print(final_curr.next)
```

This isn't all the code, but the bug appears on the first iteration of the loop. Below is the definition for ListNode:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

Comment: Why are you using a magic-number `10`?

Comment: What is the definition of `ListNode`?

Comment: Are you sure all of the code is here? Is there something between `while list1 and list2:` and `print(final_curr.next)`? Maybe something like `final_curr = final_curr.next`?

Comment: @Dai using 10 just as a placeholder. Probably not the greatest practice, but I don't see how it'd cause the problem. Dennis, no it's not all the code, but I've updated the post to reflect that the issue appears on the first iteration of the loop. If I add a print statement before and after self.next = next, only the one before will ever get printed.